# Partial derivative of $x$ w.r.t. $\bar z$?

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-derivative

My book does this :

> $x=\frac {(z+\bar z)}2$. Then $\frac {\partial x}{\partial \bar z}=\frac 12$.

But this doesn't make sense to me as $\bar z$ is a function of $z$. 
Would we say that if $y=x+x^2$ then $\frac {\partial y}{\partial x^2}=1$?

Comment: While taking partial derivatives, we consider every other variable as a constant.

Comment: This is just a piece of formalism. Just don't overthink it.

Comment: When is it that we consider a function (here, $\bar z$) as a variable?

Comment: And $ \nexists \frac{\mathrm{d}\bar{z}}{\mathrm{d} z}$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown forgive my ignorance, but could you explain what you meant by 'formalism'? My book also uses this term while stating the above.

Comment: @HritRoy Just see JCS's answer. Note that $\partial\overline z/\partial z=0=\partial z/\partial\overline z$ and that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are $\partial f/\partial\overline z=0$. It's just doesn't pay much to worry about what these "mean".

Comment: @HritRoy Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator $\partial \over \partial \overline{z}$ has a very precise definition, unlike $\partial \over \partial x^2$ that you just made up to make a point.

That definition is $\frac 12({\partial \over \partial x}+i{\partial \over \partial y})$ where $\partial \over \partial x$ and $\partial \over \partial y$ work the way you imagine.

Therefore you can see that $\partial \over \partial \overline{z}$ is linear, and satisfies ${\partial \over \partial \overline{z}}(z)=0$ and ${\partial \over \partial \overline{z}}(\overline{z})=1$.

Comment: If we _define_ it that way then I'm good.

Comment: @HritRoy That is indeed one perfectly valid definition.

Comment: Usually we take partials with respect to independent variables. $z$ and $\bar z$ though linearly independent, aren't independent

Comment: What would independent mean if not linearly independent?

Comment: isn't there a functional dependency between them? $\bar z$ is after all a function of $z$

Comment: That is unrelated. Again, the partials have a precise definition that has little to do with $z$ and $\overline{z}$. They are vectors, and linear indepedence is the only and best thing you can expect.

Comment: when you say "definition" I get the impression that we are to accept $\frac {\partial}{\partial \bar z}$ as the operator so and so. But there is some reasoning behind writing it like this. And that involves defining, first, $x$ and $y$ as functions of two "independent" variables $z$ and $\bar z$, and subsequently defining any expression as a function of $z$ and $\bar z$. Why are we justified in doing this?

Comment: Because of the last sentence in my answer. And no, that does not involve defining functions or whatever. Only the properties of the operators as they are defined allows you to justify their names.

Comment: right. Your last sentence actually makes it clear for me. Thanks

Comment: I have one (hopefully last) question. Once I accept it as a valid definition for $\frac {\partial}{\partial \bar z}$ ,how would I know that it behaves normally like a differential operator would? For instance, how would I know without checking that $\frac {\partial}{\partial \bar z}(e^z)$ is $0$ or that $\frac {\partial}{\partial \bar z}{(\bar z^2)}$ is $2\bar z$? I am asking this because we didn't define the operator in the usual way we define a partial derivative.

Comment: That's a very good question: you realise that you should not take anything from granted based on previous experience when you use new notations. But I really think that this should be a new question. The short answer for the first is that $\partial\over\partial \bar{z}$ vanishes on holomorphic functions (that's an equivalence), and for the second, simply see that the product rule for derivation applies to $\partial\over\partial x$ and $\partial\over\partial y$, therefore to $\partial\over\partial \bar{z}$ as well.

Answer (score 2):

We are talking about [Wirtinger derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives#Functions_of_one_complex_variable) here:$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\frac12\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\text{ and }\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline z}=\frac12\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

If we consider

$$x=x(z,\bar z)=\frac{z+\bar z}{2}$$

then by chain rule

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}=\frac12\qquad\frac{\partial x}{\partial \bar z}=\frac12$$

which simply means that

$$dx=\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}dz+\frac{\partial x}{\partial \bar z}d\bar z=\frac12(dz+d\bar z)$$